# Extracting public key created by an UWP app in KeyCredentialManager

Tags: tpm, microsoft, uwp

I know of an app that is using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.keycredentialmanager to generate a key pair (supposedly stored in a TPM), and sequentially uses the hash of the public key obtained from https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.security.credentials.keycredential to encrypt the app's secrets.

The API linked above does not allow other apps to access non-owned public keys which makes the above scheme fairly secure, but I wonder if the public keys of UWP apps can be accessed in some other way?